# suddently most opengles GL11 commands not working anymore

Tags: android, opengl-es

Yesterday everything works fine, but today I got many errors when I start my android opengles app: "libEGL - called unimplemented OpenGL ES API". But I changed nothing since yesterday. Are there any ideas what is going wrong, or what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have not changed anything at all.

One reason you can get this message is if OpenGL client version has been set differently.
eg: by calling

```
glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```